# Creating a formula that finds percentiles for data set in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In the following spreadsheet the cell next to `color` is a data validation list which has the options `red`, `green`, `blue` and same story for `type` except the choices are `1` and `2`. For the cells next to `ignore?` the options are `yes` and `no`

[image]

What I want to do is find the 25th,50th, and 75 percentiles for segments of my data set using formulas in the cells next to 25th,50th, and 75th percentile cells. That is, if the data validation chooses color red and type 2. I want the percentile cells to return the 3 percentiles for that segment of data.

Additionally, it would be great if `ignore?` is set to `yes` for `color` then the cells would return  the percentiles for the data segmented by given `type` only. If ignore is set to yes for both then it would just be the percentiles for the whole set.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is the 25th percentile equal to `((Max-Min)*.25)+Min`?

Comment: I was hoping to adjust the percentiles so it'd be great if the PERCENTILE function is used so that I adjust it need me.

Comment: @EngineerToast - No.  Percentiles are defined by the frequency distribution rather than the range.  The 25th percentile is the value at which 25% of the data fall below.

Comment: @fixer1234 I went and learned me some maths after I asked the question. I'm glad I don't have to use my Stats for my career.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

What you need are some array formulas. Here's the solution for the 25th percentile that doesn't use the `ignore?` data yet. I'll keep working on that one. This has to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for it to work.

```
{=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF($B$2:$B$28=$F$3,IF($C$2:$C$28=$F$4,$D$2:$D$28)),0.25)}
```

(Like I said, I'll keep working on the `ignore?` portion.)

---

Heck, we could just bundle up a few functions in some `IF` statements. Again, this is an array formula.

```
=IF(AND($H$3="yes",$H$4="yes"),PERCENTILE.EXC($D$2:$D$28,0.25),IF($H$3="yes",PERCENTILE.EXC(IF($C$2:$C$28=$F$4,$D$2:$D$28),0.25),PERCENTILE.EXC(IF($B$2:$B$28=$F$3,IF($C$2:$C$28=$F$4,$D$2:$D$28)),0.25)))
```

Comment: In my small example this would work fine, but in my real problem I actually have 4 ignore lists which make this overly complicated. Any other ideas?

Comment: What about adding a helper column to your original data set to determine if it should be included in the math?

Comment: I tried, but failed. Still a beginner in Excel.

Comment: OK, this is tricky on mobile. The helper column would be something like this pseudo formula: '=AND(OR(color=chosenColor, ignoreColor="yes"),OR(type=chosenType, ignoreType="yes"), OR(...), OR(...))'

Comment: To be precise given your example, insert a new column in `E:E` and use this formula for `E2`: `=AND(OR(B2=$G$3,$I$3="yes"),OR(C2=$G$4,$I$4="yes"),OR(...),OR(...))` and then this formula for the 25th percentile: `{=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF($E$2:$E$28,$D$2:$D$28),0.25)}`